# Find Stack Overflow users with the same IP address

Tags: discussion, users

Can someone help me with a SEDE query? I want to get all users from the same IP address. Is it possible to find or not?

For example, my IP address is `121.122.123.124`; is there any query to find other users by passing the above IP address?

Comment: IP adresses aren't part of the SEDE. They're personal information.

Comment: It is not possible for normal users. Moderators can see this, though.

Comment: And (just out of curiosity) why do you want that information?

Comment: '192.168.0.11' funny, so is mine..

Comment: @TheLostMind -  I wanted to know, how many employees are using stack overflow from the same organization. :D

Comment: AKA 'max. voting ring size' :)

Comment: Why are you asking to allow StackOverflow to compromise a poster's IP address? This is potentially dangerous information, and they should just give it away?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This information isn't publicly accessible, for obvious privacy reasons.
Neither are you likely to get this kind of information if you'd contact the SE team.

Oh, and `192.168.0.11` is a local IP, which is pretty much useless outside of your local network.

Comment: it was an example ;) - Now I can't delete my question. Can you please delete your answer ;)

Comment: @pedram yes, and the reason you don't want to post your public IP is the reason nobody else wants you to be able to find theirs. Why should you be able to delete your question? Someone else might have the same idea then can read this instead of asking it again.

Comment: okay no issue. I just hate down votes :D that's why ;)

Comment: @pedram: Downvotes on meta are also used to indicate disagreement with the post. On this question, users _might_ be downvoting because they think it's a bad idea to have that kind of info accessible.